# C# Detect UserControl width

Tags: c#, width, detect

I am using Windows Forms and I want to detect my UserControl Width and change AnchorStyle if Width been reached it limits.

Here is my Code I tried to write.

```
        if (ucControl.Width > 600)
        {
            ucControl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
            ucControl.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Top);
        }
        else
        {
            ucControl.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left);
        }
```

For now what it does is when I resize, it is already Top and Bottom Anchor. But I need Top and Bottom only when it reaches 600 and else put anchor in all directions when it is less than 600.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `Resize` event of your user control:

```
public UserControl1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     this.Resize += UserControl1_Resize;
}

private void UserControl1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Width > 600)
        ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Actually just figured out. Your option worked perfectly well. All I had to do is not to exceed Width in code that is already set in properties.

Comment: Thank you for help. i found solution. But could you also advice if there are If() statements for if I maximize my screen or put back to normal? Please, I really need this for my project.

Comment: Can I do something lie this?
            
            else if (WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;)
            {

            }

Comment: @Mark yes you can use `WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to change AnchorStyle when Width is changed. Now I wan't to put Anchor Style back when I resize it back. but I can't get correct code for back resize.
Here is my full code.

```
    static string Xpos = 348;

    private void UControl_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Main OP = (Main)ParentForm;
        if (this.Width > 699)
        {
            this.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
            this.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Top);
        }
        else if (OP.ucControl.Location = Xpos) //This bit doesn't work
        {
            this.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why when I am doing this, all my anchors stop working?
I know that I am specifying new width, because I need that. Any suggestions?

```
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
            {
                ucChat.FlowChat.Size = new Size(323, 276);
                ucChat.FlowChat.Left = (ucChat.ClientSize.Width - ucChat.FlowChat.Width) / 2;
                ucChat.FlowChat.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left);
            }
```